# Amethyst's Loader can't find an asset file

Tags: rust, loading, amethyst

I am using the Rust Amethyst game engine to load a texture named `ground.png`, but the `Loader` does not seem to find the file:

```
//...
let assets_dir = format!("{}", env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"));
let mut game = Application::build(assets_dir, Example)?.build(game_data)?;
```

My `assets_dir` is the root folder of the project and when loading my file, I append `textures/ground.png`:

```
let texture_handle = {
    let loader = world.read_resource::<Loader>();
    let texture_storage = world.read_resource::<AssetStorage<Texture>>();
    loader.load(
        "textures/ground.png",
        PngFormat,
        Default::default(),
        (),
        &texture_storage,
    )
};
```

My file directory looks like this:

```
├── src
│   └── main.rs
├── Cargo.toml
└── textures
    └── ground.png
```

The error I am getting is a `None` value when fetching the texture:

```
assert!(
    world
        .read_resource::<AssetStorage<Texture>>()
        .get(&texture_handle) != None
); //panics
```

I am using amethyst 0.8.

Comment: I presume you've solved this by now, but I would guess it has something to do with how you're running it. You need to make sure the textures folder is in the working directory of the executable. I'd also check that your file is actually named correctly.

Comment: I am getting the same problem with 0.10.0. Please tell me (a) what I should use for the asset directory in the call to `Application::build` and (b) where I should put my asset file assuming the file is called `texture/texture.png` in the call to `loader.load`.

Comment: The executable will be $WKSP/target/debug/$PROG.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this table helps you, because there are many possible answers.

All rows assume you are loading a texture using:

```rust
loader.load("path/to/texture.png", ..)
```

Paths listed are relative to the repository directory.

```
| Amethyst version | What the code uses for assets dir | How you run the executable | Where the texture should be |
| ---------------- | --------------------------------- | -------------------------- | --------------------------- |
| 0.10.0           | `"assets"`                                         | cargo run                  | `$repo/target/$profile/assets/path/to/texture.png` |
| 0.10.0           | `format!("{}/assets", env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"))` | cargo run                  | `$repo/assets/path/to/texture.png` |
| 0.10.0           | `"assets"`                                         | `./target/$profile/app`    | `$repo/assets/path/to/texture.png` |
| 0.10.0           | `env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR")`                       | `./target/$profile/app`    | `$repo/assets/path/to/texture.png` |
| 0.10.0           | `option_env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").map(|d| format!("{}/assets", d)).unwrap_or("assets")` | cargo run                  | `$repo/assets/path/to/texture.png` |
| 0.10.0           | `option_env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").map(|d| format!("{}/assets", d)).unwrap_or("assets")` | `./target/$profile/app`    | `$repo/target/$profile/assets/path/to/texture.png` |
| `master`         | `application_root_dir()`                           | cargo run                  | `$repo/assets/path/to/texture.png` |
| `master`         | `application_root_dir()`                           | `./target/$profile/app`    | `$repo/target/$profile/assets/path/to/texture.png` |
```

The first 4 are not good solutions (either dev path or player path is wrong). The 5th and 6th ways to tolerate it, which is done for you on `master` using the `application_root_dir()` function.

Comment: I think I have it working now using Rust and Amethyst nightly mode. Thanks for your help.